# How to Change the Color Behind Android Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, themes

I would like to change the color of the dimmed background that surrounds an Android dialog (not the Window background drawable) programmatically. I am using a dialog themed activity. I do not want to dim it, nor blur it.

If you imagine a dialog with three buttons, I would like to have it do something like this:

- Click A: background to translucent red
- Click B: background to translucent yellow
- Click C: background to translucent green

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can change the color of the background. The dimming is controlled by the [`dimAmount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#dimAmount) field of the layout for the dialog window (as well as the [`FLAG_DIM_BEHIND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DIM_BEHIND) flag). `dimAmount` is just a float between 0.0 and 1.0 that controls the amount of dimming (transparent to totally opaque). I think it's just an alpha blend of the existing background; there's no control of coloring as far as I've been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Activity with Theme.Dialog then you should look into your xml file for layout and then change background color of outermost container.

Comment: WindowBackground changes the dialog layout's background - not the space surrounding the dialog itself. This is what I want to change.